# Why do the electron and hole currents vanish in equilibrium in a semiconductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, semiconductor-physics

In equilibrium, there can be no net current in a semiconductor. Accounting for both drift and diffusion current, the following relationships can be derived relating the electron density, $N_{e}$, the hole carrier density, $N_{h}$, and the electrostatic potential, $\varphi$:

$$
N_{e}\propto e^{\frac{q\varphi}{\kappa T}}
$$
$$
N_{h}\propto e^{-\frac{q\varphi}{\kappa T}}
$$

where $q$ is the electron charge, $\kappa$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature. However, this relies on assuming that both the electron and hole currents separately vanish. Why should this be the case? Can't there be a net movement of electrons and holes in the same direction in equilibrium so as to cancel out the overall current?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If there is net movement of electrons and holes, then this is not an equilibrium.

Comment: I'm taking equilibrium to mean there's no net macroscopic current. Why can't there be a net movement of electrons and holes whilst keeping the combined electron and hole currents zero?

Comment: Equilibrium here means thermodynamic equilibrium, since one uses the Boltzmann distribution. One  a deeper level, macroscopic motion would imply dissipation... unless one is dealing with a superconductor/superfluid.

Comment: But the Boltzmann distribution is essentially the equations above derived from the assumption of no electron or hole currents separately. I don't want to assume what I've derived. All I want to assume is that there's no macroscopic current.

Comment: You might not be using the Boltzmann distribution directly, but you use the diffusion current, i.e. a simplified version of the Boltzmann kinetic equation, whose equilibrium solution is the Boltzmann distribution, and which requires all the assumptions normally made in statistical physics/thermodynamics. Btw, you are essentially arguing here for possibility of *perpetuum mobile*.

Comment: I do use the diffusion current, the expressions given by Fick's law, which I guess is related to Boltzmann kinetics. This certainly seems more subtle than what's presented in most texts on semiconductors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize: the collective system of Electrons and holes can move with nonzero lattice momentum vectors thus allowing for the motion you stated. However these momentum vectors do not affect conduction due to periodicity of the system.

Actually, you might have such momentum considering the periodicity of the semiconductor. Momentum of electrons and holes in semiconductors is strictly only defined for the first brillouin zone and every other momentum can be mapped back into the first Brillouin zone due to Bloch theorem based on the periodicity of the crystal. For direct band gap semiconductors, having net momentum zero typically means that electrons and/or holes have their minimum in the dispersion relation at the $\Gamma$-point. This is the origin of the first brillouin zone. But due to periodicity it is equal to the $\Gamma $-point of every brillouin zone. And the Brillouin zones are only distinct by the lattice Momentum vectors $\mathbf{G} $, that meet the condition
$$
e^{i\mathbf{G}\cdot \mathbf{ R} } =1
$$
which is the Bragg condition.
For indirect band gap semiconductors like silicon, the conduction band minimum is not at the $\Gamma$-point but as those are still periodic, the line of reasoning holds true still.

**Ashcroft - Mermin "solid state physics"** and **Sze "Physics of semiconductor devices"** are a good starter for this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In equilibrium an electron or hole will have, on average, no net momentum. Any disturbance of this equilibrium will be transient and dissipated by electron-phonon scattering.

Comment: How do you justify your first sentence? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris It is justified by the second.